# C++. unique_ptr и квадратные скобки

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, unique-ptr

Эта штука работает:

```
int * CurrentData = Alloc().allocate(10);
CurrentData[0] = 5;
```

А эта нет:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> CurrentData = Alloc().allocate(10);
CurrentData[0] = 5;
```

Исправьте вторую чтоб они вели себя одинаково.

Comment: В объекте unique_ptr не предусмотрен оператор квадратные скобки

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я уже понял по выводу компилятора, но должен же быть аналог?

Comment: вы знаете о std::vector?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я его прям щас пишу) домашка в универе такая

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov и зачем же вам тогда умный указатель?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ компилируется, сейчас проверю

Comment: 1. Не  серьезно писать "Эта штука работает" в сайте для программистов.  2.   Старайтесь формулировать качественный  вопрос , а не безобразное задание или команду. От меня данному "вопросу" 3 минуса..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У шаблона `std::unique_ptr` есть специализация, которая принимает массивы. Там есть реализация `operator[]`. Поэтому в вашем случае скорее всего подойдёт такой вариант:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]>
```

Это тип умного указателя, хранящего массив `int`ов. Для освобождения памяти по умолчанию будет вызван оператора `delete[]` вместо `delete` для скалярной версии.

Comment: Поскольку выделение памяти производилось `Alloc().allocate(10)` то и для высвобождения потребуется использовать `deallocate`, а это требует конструктора `std::unique_ptr` с deleter.